I'm looking for resources that involve concretely taking Lebesgue integral of functions (non-axiomatic and computation focused)
I want to practice finding the Lebesgue integrals of certain functions. My source of inspiration is integrating Dirac delta functions and anything relating to differential equations like Green's function.
I've read some books on measure theory, but they only give the axiomatic and motivational sides of Lebesgue integration, and as a result I can't get the concept to "stick."
As a result, I want some books, pages, class notes, homeworks, videos, etc... that give good computational problems on performing Lebesgue integration. These problems should preferably be less axiomatic and proof focused, and more on finding values or solutions to problems.

The measure theory books that you read—did you do the exercises in them?

Read my statement again. Take Tao's Analysis, volume II. A quick look through will show you that the problems revolving around Lebesgue Measure and integration -- chapters 7 and 8 -- are entirely or almost entirely focused around proving lemmas or theorems.

For many computational problems, it makes no difference if the Lebesgue integral or some more elementary integral notion is used. Are you interested in those too, or do they have to contain something "Lebesgue-specific"?

@Stefan Lebesgue-specific would be preferable, but if there's a nice computational example of integrating, say, a polynomial function by using the Lebesgue method instead of Riemann method then I wouldn't mind looking at that. An example of the type of thing I would like to see an integral for would be a Dirac delta function (and by extension a green's function).

The Lebesgue integral isn't an alternative to Riemann integration, it's the completion of it. If a function is Riemann integrable (like a polynomial), it's Lebesgue integrable and the integrals are equal (See Proposition 8.4.1 of the Tao book you mentioned). Or if a function is a pointwise limit of integrable functions (like a delta function), the integral of the limit is the limit of the integrals (monotone or dominated convergence theorem). So other than toy examples like the characteristic function of $\mathbb{Q} \cap [0,1]$, “techniques of Lebesgue integration” isn't really a thing.
